# Google App Engine Logging in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, logging

I can't find much on logging onto Google App Engine using Flexible environment and NodeJS.

As the [docs says](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-application-logs), one is able to write its own logging messages using the standard `stdout` and `stderr`. But this is simple logging, and I would like to have something a little bit more refined.

In particular, the Log Views in Google Cloud Platform Console allows the user to filter logs on their severity levels:

1. Critical
2. Error
3. Warning
4. Info
5. Debug
6. Any log level

I would like to find a way to use those levels in my applications, so that I can read logs much better.

By default, if I print to `stdout` using `console.log()` the logs will only appear if I filter by "Any log level", and I have no option to select a severity level.

I have tried to use `winston-gae` as reported on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-application-logs), but without any success. Maybe I have configured it wrong?

To be more clear, I would like to be able to do something like this in Python ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/)):

```
import logging
import webapp2
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.debug('This is a debug message')
        logging.info('This is an info message')
        logging.warning('This is a warning message')
        logging.error('This is an error message')
        logging.critical('This is a critical message')
        self.response.out.write('Logging example.')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to look at the Google Cloud Node.js client library, that can help you call the Stackdriver Logging API in order to log structured log entries: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#google-stackdriver-logging-beta